# Changing function argument name breaks function

Tags: r, data.table

I am having an issue with a function in R where changing the local name of a function argument causes the code to break. The problematic name is not the name of any variable in the global scope.

Here is my code.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(data.table)

data <- fread("data/pwt91_cleaned_swiid.csv")

setkey(data,alpha3,year)

# Some details -- ignore this, only here for completeness...
data <- data[ year >= 1968]
data[ subRegion_new == "Africa", subRegion_new := "AFR"]
data[ subRegion_new == "East Asian Tigers", subRegion_new := "EAT"]
data[ subRegion_new == "United States", subRegion_new := "USA"]
data[ subRegion_new == "Latin America and the Caribbean", subRegion_new := "LAC"]

# Here is the relevant section
computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion <- function(data, metric, region) {

  temp <- data[ subRegion_new %in% c("LAC",region), .(average = mean(na.omit(get(metric)))), by = .(isLAC, year)]
  temp <- dcast(temp, year ~ isLAC, value.var = "average")
  setnames(temp,"0",region)
  setnames(temp,"1","LAC")
  temp[ , (paste0(region,"_",metric,"_gap")) := LAC - get(region)]
  return(temp)

}

for (region in c("AFR","EAT","USA")) 
{
  for (metric in c("lrtfpna_chg7","lrgdpnaPerCapita_chg7_nonTFP","lrgdpnaPerCapita_chg7"))
  {
    assign(paste0("LACvs",region,"_",metric), computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion(data,metric,region))
  }
}
```

When I try to run this code, I get the error message

```
 Error in setnames(temp, "0", region) : 
  Items of 'old' not found in column names: [0]. Consider skip_absent=TRUE.
```

I know that this is because the first line of `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()` is failing to find any observations where `isLAC == 0` is true. The details of what this means aren't important I don't think. I also find that running the code inside the function `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()` for specific values (strings) of the arguments works. Furthermore, I find that replacing the code for `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()` with

```
computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion <- function(data, x, y) {
  
  temp <- data[ subRegion_new %in% c("LAC",y), .(average = mean(na.omit(get(x)))), by = .(isLAC, year)]
  temp <- dcast(temp, year ~ isLAC, value.var = "average")
  setnames(temp,"0",y)
  setnames(temp,"1","LAC")
  temp[ , (paste0(y,"_",x,"_gap")) := LAC - get(y)]
  return(temp)
  
}
```

fixes the issue entirely. As does using anything other than `metric` and `region` as in the original example.

Lastly, this appears not to be an issue of using the same name for the looping variable (`region`, `metric`) as inside the body of the function `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()`. I know this because (1) changing the looping variables does not remove the error message, and (2) changing the name of the variables inside the body of the function `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()` avoids the error message, *even if* I also change the looping variables to those same corresponding variables.

I have a solution, it seems, which is to just change the variable used in the definition of `computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion()`. But there is clearly something I do not understand. I hope someone can clarify.

If you want to replicate this, you can find the relevant code and data on github:

code: https://github.com/nfernandez-arias/inequality-and-productivity-growth-in-lac-countries/blob/master/adjustedGrowthGaps_rollingWindows.R

dataset: https://github.com/nfernandez-arias/inequality-and-productivity-growth-in-lac-countries/blob/master/data/pwt91_cleaned_swiid.csv

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the issue with `setnames` you could change the values before using `dcast`.

However, this would return an error in the next line (`temp[ , (paste0(region,"_",metric,"_gap")) := LAC - get(region)]`). We can add an `if` statement to check that.

```
computeRawGaps_LACvsRegion <- function(data, x, y) {
  temp <- data[ subRegion_new %in% c("LAC",y), .(average = mean(na.omit(get(x)))), by = .(isLAC, year)]
  temp[, isLAC := fcase(isLAC == "0", y, 
                        isLAC == "1", "LAC")]
  temp <- dcast(temp, year ~ isLAC, value.var = "average")
  if(y %in% names(temp)) temp[ , (paste0(y,"_",x,"_gap")) := LAC - get(y)]
  return(temp)
}
```